# Is there any existing implementation of List/Vector

Tags: mql4

Is there any existing implementation of list of string, integer etc. where we can add element, remove element directly, without caring of the size of the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <Object.mqh>
#include <Arrays\ArrayObj.mqh>

class CElementInt : public CObject{
    int m_value;                  
                    CElement(const int value){m_value=value);
                   ~CElement(){}
};

CArrayObj *list;

int OnInit(){
     list = new CArrayObj();
     return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnTick(){
     if(TRUE){
        list.Add(new CElement(100));
     }else{
        list.Delete(new CElement(100));
     }
}
```

You can add any kind of Cobject and its relatives classes into `CArrayObj`.